# SQL Server Single Record Delete Not Complete in 3+ minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 810 records in SQL Server 2005 that looks like this:

- UniqueId
- FileId
- FileName
- FileSize
- FileType
- FileContents
- FileDescription

When I try to run the following query:

```
DELETE FROM Attachments
WHERE UniqueId = 1122 AND FileId = 923
```

it runs for 3+ minutes and doesn't complete.  The table is really small, the file size is 4900 bytes, and I'm only trying to delete a single record.  Anyone have any ideas of what could be slowing this thing to a crawl?

EDIT:
I very much appreciate the time each of you took to try to answer my question.  I would +1 each of you, but I can't do that yet.  We did finally find the answer...we had to rebuild the indexes.  The rebuild took much longer than we expected (10minutes or so), but once we did it the table resumed functioning as normal.  Evidently someone turned off the maintenance for that database and forgot to turn it back on.  Hopefully, someone else can benefit from our misfortune.

Comment: Very curios your statement is perfect!!

Comment: Did you try running profiler to see if there's anything locking the table?

Comment: We checked.  No one is locking it.

Comment: I would be surprised if index fragmentation was the problem. Unless the index was completely disabled, you should still be doing a seek. If you did a rebuild, you'd have also updated the corresponding statistic which evicts any query plans from the cache that rely on that statistic. So you may have just had a bad plan. Next time, take a look at sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks and see what your query is waiting on. It may not be blocked, but you'll get a good idea of what it's doing and for how long.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll check that out if this ever crops up again.  And yes, the index was completely disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could have a trigger that is doing other work. You could have blocking from another process. Or you could have cacade delete turned on and instead of deleting one record you are delteing millions. Or you could have hundreds of FKs that have to be checked.

But check for blocking first!

Comment: Triggers: there aren't any on that table. Cascade Delete: there are no downstream tables.  Foreign Keys: there is one foreign key to another table where the UniqueId exists, so i'm fairly certain that isn't it.  Blocking: how do i check that? Out of this list, it's the most likely issue.

Comment: Nope, it's not being blocked either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else is doing an insert or update operation which locks the table you work with.